# Outlook 2011 category colors - Windows Color Palette?

Tags: ms-office, color, customization

Does anybody know what are the RGB "equivalents" of the category colors that MS uses in the Windows version of Oulook 2010?

Just starting to use a Mac "for real work" (vs tinkering with it as a set-top player in the past). I'm setting up my Mac Outlook/Office environment "just so" and one of the things I'm missing is to be able to construct the same categories and *associated colors* that I have been using on Windows.

I've been mucking around, and I already have the proper list of categories loaded, but I can't figure out what are the equivalent to the MS-provided colors. The Apple-supplied palette is to "bright" for my taste. I've seen that it's possible to create new colors/palettes (while in the Windows version it's not - that's an improvement IMO), but I haven't been able to find the RGB specs of the colors themselves...

Thanks!

EDIT: To clarify, the "colors" I'm looking for are the ones you get in Outlook 2010.

I've got a screenshot of the ones I mean:

[image: Outlook 2010 Category Colors]

They have names such as "Olive", "Blue", "Dark Red", "Dark Maroon"....

Comment: updated my answer to include all of the standard colors.

Comment: Added an self-response to showcase Microsoft's official list of RGB Values, thanks to @hoss

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Default Outlook Colors]

Using `/Applications/Utilities/DigitalColor Meter.app` set to `RGB as Actual Value, 8-bit` and then hover over each color to find it's RGB color values.

### Color Values:

```
## COLOR       HEX     (RRR GGG BBB)
 1 Red         #E7A1A2 (231 161 162)
 2 Orange      #F9BA89 (249 186 137)
 3 Peach       #F7DD8F (247 221 143)
 4 Yellow      #FCFA90 (252 250 144)
 5 Green       #78D168 (120 209 104)
 6 Teal        #9FDCC9 (159 220 201)
 7 Olive       #C6D2B0 (198 210 176)
 8 Blue        #9DB7E8 (157 183 232)
 9 Purple      #B5A1E2 (181 161 226)
10 Maroon      #daaec2 (218 174 194)
11 Steel       #dad9dc (218 217 220)
12 Dark Steel  #6b7994 (107 121 148)
13 Grey        #bfbfbf (191 191 191)
14 Dark Grey   #6f6f6f (111 111 111)
15 Black       #4f4f4f ( 79  79  79)
16 Dark Red    #c11a25 (193  26  37)
17 Dark Orange #e2620d (226  98  13)
18 Dark Peach  #c79930 (199 153  48)
19 Dark Yellow #b9b300 (185 179   0)
20 Dark Green  #368f2b ( 54 143  43)
21 Dark Teal   #329b7a ( 50 155 122)
22 Dark Olive  #778b45 (119 139  69)
23 Dark Blue   #2858a5 ( 40  88 165)
24 Dark Purple #5c3fa3 ( 92  63 163)
25 Dark Maroon #93446b (147  68 107)
```

*Note: color values returned by color meter might be slightly different based on the selected color profile.*

Make a custom color and use the RGB Sliders and enter the decimal values above.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Hoss thanks for the info - but these are not the colors I'm looking for (or at least, not all). I've edited the question to show the ones I'm refering to.

Comment: open `/Applications/Utilities/DigitalColor Meter.app`then hover over each color to get it's RGB value as needed. I'll update my answer to include this. but if I have a moment I'll enumerate the attached colors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, both for giving me the info, and also "teaching me how to fish"!!

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft provides this mapping of color name to RGB value:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee203806(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee203806%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the Outlook 2016 colors as captured by colorcop:

[image: Outlook 2016 Category Colors]

```
#f07d88
#33bab1
#b9c0cb
#910a19
#1c6367
#ff8c00
#a3b367
#4c596e
#ce4b28
#5c6a22
#fecb6f
#55abe5
#ababab
#a47332
#254069
#fff100
#a895e2
#666666
#b0a923
#562685
#5fbe7d
#e48bb5
#474747
#026802
#80275d
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the link provided by @The Face of Bo above (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee203806%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx), the matching RGB values for the "named" MS colors are:

```
  Base R,G,B    Color name   
|--------------|------------|  
 255, 255,255   No color     
 214, 37, 46    Red  
 240, 108, 21   Orange   
 255, 202, 76   Peach    
 255, 254, 61   Yellow   
 74, 182, 63    Green    
 64, 189, 149   Teal     
 133, 154, 82   Olive    
 50, 103, 184   Blue     
 97, 61, 180    Purple   
 163, 78, 120   Maroon   
 196, 204, 221  Steel    
 140, 156, 189  Dark steel   
 196, 196, 196  Gray     
 165, 165, 165  Dark gray    
 28, 28, 28     Black    
 175, 30, 37    Dark red     
 177, 79, 13    Dark orange  
 171, 123, 5    Dark peach   
 153, 148, 0    Dark yellow  
 53, 121, 43    Dark green   
 46, 125, 100   Dark teal    
 95, 108, 58    Dark olive   
 42, 81, 145    Dark blue    
 80, 50, 143    Dark purple   
 130, 55, 95    Dark maroon
```

(The formatting is a bit messed up, but I can't manage to get it "nice looking" as @hoss accepted answer!)​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​