# Mac Office 2011 - Exporting a Color Palette

Tags: ms-office, settings, color, exchange-activesync

Just got into using Mac "full time" for work, and as I'm a bit of a nit-picker, I want to get things looking/behaving just so.

Thanks to the help of the group, I've been able to get my Category list looking "right" (see [Outlook 2011 category colors - Windows Color Palette?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96056/outlook-2011-category-colors-windows-color-palette)) but now that I have my "Office 2010 Categories" Color Palette, I have had a couple of co-workers ask about getting it into their systems:

[image: Office 2011 Mac Custom Colors with Office 2010 Win Colors]

The thing is, looking at the "gear" menu in the Palette, I can see options to IMPORT new palettes, but not to export/save them:

[image: Office 2011 Color Palette Management Options]

Any idea of how to export them for re-use? Or how to create a "palette" file I could import in several systems?

Thanks!

Javier

PS: BTW, I wonder why Outlook Mac doesn't import the categories from Exchange as it does in Windows -- I've set up Outlook 2007/2010 in several computers and in all of them the Category list is "synched" automagically...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a nice GUI way that I could find (bad on Apple)   but the palette file is in ~/Library/Colors/xxxx.clr

Pick it up from there and distribute the file can load with the dropdown on the gear.   Loading it effectively moves the file into this directory on that machine.

Comment: I actually thought it would be something under "Office" - I hadn't realized the color picker dialog was part of the OS and I was going to lay the blame on MS -- But I agree with you, it seems strange that after all the care Apple takes on things related to color fidelity, and allowing you to define custom palettes, so little care is taken to let you export the settings. Thanks for pointing out the way!!!